# Find all where hstore does not contain any specified keys

Tags: postgresql, hstore, negation

In the [hstore docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html#AEN170846) there is a documented operator to check if the hstore contains all specified keys:

> **Operator:** hstore ?& text[]
>
> **Description:** does hstore contain all specified keys?
>
> **Example:** 'a=>1,b=>2'::hstore ?& ARRAY['a','b']
>
> **Result:** => t

My use case is the exact opposite: I want to check if the hstore does *not* contain all specified keys.

So `'a=>1,b=>2'::hstore SOME_OPERATOR ARRAY['b','c']` should return false since `'a=>1,b=>2'` contains b.

I tried `!?&` but to no surprise, that didn't work. Is there such an operator? Or a method to negate the documented one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negate the condition and change the operator to `?|` so that it does not match *any* keys from the array:

```
select *
from some_table
where not (some_column ?| ARRAY['b','c'])
```